# why my python initialization does'nt work?

Tags: python

I have been learning about the `__init__` method and thought to try it out:

```
o = 5
int.__init__(o, 7)
print(o)
```

it is supposed to change the value of o to 7, but it does not. why?

Comment: It's because integers in Python are immutable. Strings, numbers, booleans, `None` and tuples are immutable as well, just to answer that question in advance.

Comment: `o=7` is waaaay simpler

Comment: That doesn't change the value of the integer though... ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think OP is looking for a clever way to circumvent the immutability. The question is probably how the immutability is implemented.

Comment: How can I initialize an object using the __init__ function though? in its raw way

Comment: You can assign a new value to `o`; you cannot modify the `int` value currently assigned to `o`.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @coolness usually you don't call `__init__` explicitly. Objects are instantiated via `SomeClass()` which calls `__new__` and `__init__`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @timgeb I just want to learn how it works behind the scenes, that's all

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you want to know, though.

Comment: @timbeg what functions are involved when initializing an object

Comment: @coolness define "initialize"

Comment: How much detail do you want? I would refer you to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html, specifically section 3.3.1.

Comment: @timbeg creating an object with values

Comment: @coolness ok, If you call `SomeClass()` then first `__new__` and then `__init__` is called.

Comment: @chepner well thank you, it is actually very helpful

Comment: Also a search keyword for you: "immutable". I'm sure you will find it used in Python docs or Python-related questions here.